# HiddenField value doesn't get removed

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a javascript function that moves items between 2 select multiple box, when I move item from the source select box to the destination select box, I add the value to my HiddenField so that I can access in code behind, works fine but when I move item(s) from the destination select box back to the source select box, I try to use : hidMemType.value = ""; to clear the hiddenfield. I thought this works but apparently in the event of a postback, the item still gets stuck in the destination box. Please advice, thanks.

```
// Move items to and fro select box
        function move(sourceFrom, sourceTo) {

            var hidOutlet = document.getElementById('<%=hdnOutlet.ClientID%>');
            var hidMemType = document.getElementById('<%=hdnMemType.ClientID%>');
            var hidMemStatus = document.getElementById('<%=hdnMemStatus.ClientID%>');

            var arrFrom = new Array();
            var arrTo = new Array();
            var arrLU = new Array();
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < sourceTo.options.length; i++) {
                arrLU[sourceTo.options[i].text] = sourceTo.options[i].value;
                arrTo[i] = sourceTo.options[i].text;
            }
            var fLength = 0;
            var tLength = arrTo.length;
            for (i = 0; i < sourceFrom.options.length; i++) {
                arrLU[sourceFrom.options[i].text] = sourceFrom.options[i].value;
                if (sourceFrom.options[i].selected && sourceFrom.options[i].value != "") {
                    arrTo[tLength] = sourceFrom.options[i].text;
                    tLength++;
                } else {
                    arrFrom[fLength] = sourceFrom.options[i].text;
                    fLength++;
                }
            }

            sourceFrom.length = 0;
            sourceTo.length = 0;
            var ii;

            for(ii = 0; ii < arrFrom.length; ii++) 
            {
            var no = new Option();
            no.value = arrLU[arrFrom[ii]];
            no.text = arrFrom[ii];
            sourceFrom[ii] = no; // SENDS VALUE FROM DESTINATION BOX BACK TO SOURCE BOX
            hidMemType.value = ""; // TRY TO CLEAR MY HIDDEN FIELD HERE
            }


            for (ii = 0; ii < arrTo.length; ii++) {
                var no = new Option();
                no.value = arrLU[arrTo[ii]];
                no.text = arrTo[ii];
                //sourceTo.options.add(no);
                sourceTo[ii] = no;

                if (sourceTo == (document.getElementById('<%=outletToBox.ClientID%>'))) {
                    hidOutlet.value += no.value + "|";
               }
                if (sourceTo == (document.getElementById('<%=QualMemTypeToBox.ClientID%>'))) {
                    hidMemType.value += no.value + "|";
                }
                if (sourceTo == (document.getElementById('<%=MemStatusToBox.ClientID%>'))) {
                    hidMemStatus.value += no.value + "|";
                }
            }              



        (sourceTo).focus();

            if (sourceTo == (document.getElementById('<%= outletFromBox.ClientID%>'))) {
                (sourceFrom).focus();
            }
            if (sourceTo == (document.getElementById('<%= QualMemTypeFromBox.ClientID %>'))) {
                (sourceFrom).focus();
            }
            if (sourceTo == (document.getElementById('<%= MemStatusFromBox.ClientID %>'))) {
                (sourceFrom).focus();
            }

}
```

**Code Behind:**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

 PopulateSelectBoxes(hdnMemType, QualMemTypeToBox, QualMemTypeFromBox)

end Sub

 Protected Sub PopulateSelectBoxes(ByVal hdnSelectBox As HiddenField, ByVal selectBox As HtmlSelect, ByVal selectBox_Frm As HtmlSelect)

   Dim hiddenMemType(selectBox.Items.Count - 1) As String
        hiddenMemType = (Split(hdnSelectBox.Value, "|"))

        Dim tempTable As String = ""
        For Each item In hiddenMemType
            If (tempTable.IndexOf(item) = -1) Then
                If item <> "" Then
                    tempTable += item + "|"
                End If
            End If
        Next

        If tempTable <> "" Then
            hiddenMemType = (Split(tempTable, "|"))

            'We remove the items that exist in the ToBox
            For Each item In hiddenMemType
                selectBox_Frm.Items.Remove(item)
            Next

            selectBox.Items.Clear()
            selectBox.DataSource = hiddenMemType
            selectBox.DataBind()
        End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking out loud here.
Have you tried this in the code behind:

```
myControl.value = Nothing
```

Maybe that will work.

Edit:
You could also try putting a default value in there and if its the default value you just dont do anything with it. and if you are done with the current value just change it back to the default

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling ViewState on your hidden controls - maybe that's what's preserving the values.

Answer (score 0):

In your JS `move` function I imagine that the `for` loop which follows `hidMemType.value = "";` is setting `hidMemType.value` again. Have you checked that this is not the case? I would enclose that `for` loop in an `if` to ensure that it isn't hit when it shouldn't be.

I would also add an `alert` at the end of `function move()` to show exactly what `hidMemType.value` is on exit.